Return max value ignoring inner table where clause
Currently playing around with some sample examples from here:
https://www.sql-practice.com/
SELECT 
    *, d.specialty, p.last_name
FROM
    admissions a
JOIN
    doctors d ON a.attending_doctor_id = d.doctor_id
JOIN
    patients p ON a.patient_id = p.patient_id
WHERE
    a.diagnosis IS NOT 'Pregnant'

I'm trying to create an additional column to find each patient_id latest admission date, ignoring the inner query where the diagnosis may be pregnant.
I only want to see the latest date where the patient doesn't have an allergy to Penicillin. I want to see all records from the admissions table even if the new 'latest admission' field returns null.
Any suggestions please?

Please read how to create a minimal reproducible example and do not link off to external pages. Escpecially not if your question doesn't stand alone without external information because people can't understand the question anymore in case they don't want to open sites they don't know or the site you linked goes offline.

Syntax error. Use standard <> comparison, instead of IS NOT.

You need a CTE for this and to join to your existing query.
    WITH pat_max_admin as
    (
      select patient_id, max(admission_date) as latest_admission_date 
      FROM admissions
      group by patient_id
    )
SELECT 
    a.*, d.specialty, p.last_name, p2.latest_admission_date
FROM
    admissions a
JOIN
    doctors d ON a.attending_doctor_id = d.doctor_id
JOIN
    patients p ON a.patient_id = p.patient_id
LEFT JOIN pat_max_admin p2 ON p2.patient_id = p.patient_id
WHERE
    a.diagnosis IS NOT 'Pregnant'
    ;

You may need to play around a bit with the WHERE filters to get your desired result

Syntax error. Use standard <> comparison, instead of IS NOT.
